# About node js logic in four in row game

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

I'm working on node js right now. I'm developing Four in row game. But right now I'm stuck at one step. I want to check my table cell applied or not? Because I want to check it from server side. If applied then I need to skip that cell. Otherwise I need to apply new css of player2. So can you please give a condition for css checking?

Comment: For multiplayer games like that is common to open a WebSocket to all clients(players) and when a client does a move, he just sends the information to the server and then the server sends the information to ALL clients and only then the UI updates, this is mean that all logic and state of the game is in your server.

Comment: looks like English grammar issue